# Loop in script on remote server doesn't work

Tags: shell-script, ssh

```
#!bin/bash
client=`cat temp.txt`
ssh node2@192.168.1.190 'while read line; do mkdir -p /tmp/$line ; done <<< "$client"'
```

`cat temp.txt` has 2 lines:

```
nk124
nk124
```

Above is my script, it does not work. There is no error during execution but does not create directories.

Comment: One important thing to notice is that since you are enclosing the command string with `'`s, the `$client` will not be expanded to its respective value.   This may not be the complete reason your script is not working, but this is certanly not doing what you intend it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the `<<< $client` portion out from the enclosing `'`s:

```
#!/bin/bash

client=`cat temp.txt`
ssh node2@192.168.1.190 'while read line; do mkdir -p /tmp/$line ; done' <<< "$client"
```

OBS: There was a missing `/` in the shebang too.  Use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!bin/bash`

Comment: Yup, but it's better to just skip the `cat` entirely and do it in one line: `ssh node2@192.168.1.190 'while read line; do mkdir -p /tmp/$line ; done < temp.txt'`

Comment: That's correct @evilsoup.  What we actually don't know is if the user's question is just a simplification of a more complex script he has and used this to depict where/what is his current problem.  He possibly does need to use the contents of a variable.  So, I think it is better to leave the didactic approach and address just the issue he reported.  Your comment in the other hand is good and informative if this is not the case and he missed the straight through approach ;).
BTW, the `<temp.txt` in your approach should be left out of the enclosing `'` too, otherwise the same issue will happen.